# Dataframe grouping and deleting rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have grouped a dataframe with two criteria: years and group(1,2,3,4) as follows

```
df.groupby([df.index.year,'Group']).count()['Column1']
              Group
2009  1            1
      2            2
      3            8
      4            0
2010  1            3
      2            1
      3            9
      4            2
```

I would like to get rid of group 4 from year 2009 directly from the grouped data. thanks

Comment: Any reason you can't remove those rows from "df" before the grouping?

Comment: Is more about how to handle dataframe with multiindex. The idea is to have better skills managing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drop` with tuple:

```
df1 = df.groupby([df.index.year,'Group']).count()['Column1']

df1 = df1.drop((2009,4))
```

OR

```
df1.drop((2009,4), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
df.groupby([df.index.year,'Group']).count()['Column1'].filter(lambda x: x.index[0]!=2009 or max(x.Group)!=4)
```